# addEventListener to submenu links only, without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I would like to add an event listener to the `#nav ul a` links only. **Ordinerly i would use jQuery for this, but I can't with this project.**

Basically I need to change the style of the sub menu `<UL>` when it’s child link `<A>` has keyboard (tab) focus.

So, the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Top 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Top 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>              
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Top 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
      </ul>              
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've got this far with the Javascript but it's also selecting the top `<ul id="nav">` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function linkOn(e) {
            var target = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
            target.style.color = "green";
        }
        function linkOff(e) {
            var target = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
            target.style.color = "";
        }           

        function addListeners() {

            var arrayTop = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayTop.length; i++)
            {
                arrayTop[i].addEventListener("focus",linkOn,false);
                arrayTop[i].addEventListener("blur",linkOff,false);
            }               
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', addListeners, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: _"It's also selecting the top `<ul id="nav">` element"_ - no, it isn't. Your code is fine so far, aside from IE support. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/zcE86/

Comment: Oh. Are you talking about the `<a>` elements like `Top #1` and `Top #2` whose `parent.parent` is `ul#nav`? What should happen when those anchors are focused?

Comment: Ideally nothing should happen to them. Could you elaborate on why IE won’t support this, i can see that it can't but don’t know what it's not supporting?

Comment: For IE use `attachEvent(...)` instead of `addEventListener(..., false)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit iterate through the li's for `#nav` and assign to their links... querySelectorALL would make things so much easier though.

---

### Hard Method

http://jsfiddle.net/Btu4m/

```
        var nodeList = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("ul");

        for (var x = 0; x < nodeList.length; x++)
        {
            var arrayTop = nodeList[x].getElementsByTagName("a");
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayTop.length; i++)
            {
                arrayTop[i].addEventListener("focus",linkOn,false);
                arrayTop[i].addEventListener("blur",linkOff,false);
            }      
        }
```

### querySelectorAll Method

http://jsfiddle.net/Btu4m/1/

```
        var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("#nav ul a");

        for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
        {
            nodeList[i].addEventListener("focus",linkOn,false);
            nodeList[i].addEventListener("blur",linkOff,false);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly, and the backgroundColor in your jsFiddle was a good touch for demonstration.

Comment: @Treb `querySelectorAll()` is not 100% browser compatible. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13

Comment: @Treb I think it's because IE doesn't support [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer)